# How to display the value of a variable on the screen?

Tags: android, variables, textview

I know this is very basic question, but I need to know, how I can display the contents of a variable on the screen.

Do I use a textview in my layout?

I have a textview box and I can set it to say something in the editor but I need to write the contents of a variable so I can do some error checking.

Anyone help?

Comment: Are you having a problem setting the textView to the value of the variable? If so, please post code showing your attempt. Also, why not just use the logger for this purpose?

Comment: Displaying the variable in a textview works. Is there anything wrong with setting a breakpoint in your debugger?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have a TextView named textViewName defined in your layout XML file, you can just do something like this in your Activity class:

```
setContentView(R.layout.layoutName);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
textView.setText("text you want to display");
```

Is this what you're looking for? If you don't need to display it to the screen, and just want to debug, just use Log() and logcat to view the messages.

Comment: That's the fella Thanks!  (I thought it was simple but couldn't find it :))

Answer (score 4):

If you have a list on the screen , then to not lose the list and still show change use ,  taking @Matt's example.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
textView.setText("text you want to display");
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In the Activity...

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    int myValue = deriveMyValue();
    String message =
        myValue == -1 ?
            "The value is invalid." :
            "The value is " + myValue;
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    tv.setText(message);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that Just needed the Textview stuff, you people are good!

Answer (score 2):

```
int count=7;
     TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
tv.setText("you have entered"+count+"as the integer");
```

As you can see,you can include other data types like integers also in the setText block

Comment: Dont't forget spaces after "entered" and before "as" ;)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you want to concatenate a string and a variable, you can use the "+" operator as you would do in System.out.print