# VariableDeclaratorId and misplace

Tags: java, android

I'm new to JAva and Android, and I'm working on my first test app.

I have this code (This is the whole code):

```
package test.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    int num_seeds = 15 ;
    int num_coins = 100 ;
    int seed_buy_price = 10 ;
    int seed_sell_price = 8 ;
    String S_num_seeds = Integer.toString(num_seeds) ;

    TextView textView_seeds_current_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_seeds_current_display) ;

    textView_seeds_current_display.setText(S_num_seeds) ;

}
```

But Eclipse shows me an error on last line:
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token "S_num_seeds", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this 
     token
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

I'm new to Java and I still can not understand this quite well. Could somebody please point me what am I doing wrong? I think I'm following the advice from here:

[How to display the value of a variable on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821051/how-to-display-the-value-of-a-variable-on-the-screen)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of procedural code:

```
   textView_seeds_current_display.setText(S_num_seeds);
```

appears in your class definition. It needs to appear within a method. It might need to be in a constructor.

Comment: Thanks. It is my first Java project and I do not understand quite well enough. You explained it very well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Part of the community expectation here is that you "accept" an answer to your question if it helps you. To do this, click on the outline green checkmark.

Answer (score -2):

The code seams to be fine ...

Some times I have the eclipse showing similar error when the line is OK. Try the following: position cursor on the line, press ctrl d (removes the line) and then press ctrl z (restores the line removed). If it's a "fake" error, it will disapper.

good luck

Comment: Someone down voted the answer, but I can assure that the information is correct. You can achive the same selecting in Eclipse the menu "Project" and then "Clean", but it would take longer.