# Java "VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token"

Tags: java, class

I'm working on a little project for fun, that's essentially a little combat emulator. I'm trying to use a class similar to struct in C++, as in using it to create an object (in this case, a character or "entity", as the class is called). I'm getting the error in the title when attempting to call any integer in said class from the main function.

```
class entity{
    public int health;
    public int accuracy;
    public int power;
    public int defense;
}
```

And

```
public class Tutorial {
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    entity player;
    player.health = 100;  // Issue on the health part
    player.accuracy = 19; // Issue on the accuracy part
    player.power = 15;    // Issue on the power part
    player.defense = 18;  // I think you get it by now...
```

I've been looking around for a while to find some explanation, but there's none that I could find that explain the nature of the error as well as possible fixes for my situation. If I could get those, it would be wonderful.

Comment: You declare an `entity` object, but never initialize it. Check out the `new` keyword in java.

Comment: @Takendarkk Compile errors prevent run-time exceptions ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is expecting a variable declaration on the line

```
player.health = 100;
```

but is finding an assignment instead. The statements

```
Entity player = new Entity();
player.health = 100; 
player.accuracy = 19; 
player.power = 15; 
player.defense = 18;
```

should be in a code block such as a method or constructor rather than the class block

Answer (score 2):

[Procedural code *cannot* be written directly in a class definition.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12558000/2864740) The code is causing *syntax errors* because it's not legal to do so.

Instead, put the code in an appropriate *method* or [initialization block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487889/java-initialization-blocks). (I do *not* think an initialization block is appropriate here, so I am trivially showing a "factory method".)

As such, consider an approach like

```
// This is a member variable declaration, which is why it's OK
// to have a (static) method call provide the value.
// Alternatively, player could also be initialized in the constructor.
Entity player = makeMeAPlayer();

static Entity makeMeAPlayer() {
    // Create and return entity; the code is inside a method
    Entity player = new Entity();
    player.health = 100;
    // etc.
    return player;
}
```

(I've also cleaned up the type to match Java Naming Conventions - follow suite!)

Comment: Whew. I had a million typos :|

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to suffer from highly accurate yet not terrible intuitive messaging for VariableDeclaratorId.

```
 @PostMapping("/showCompany")
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("company") CompaniesDAO company, company_name, company_function) {
```

Will produce:

```
Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete FormalParameter
```

This is telling you that is need the variable type like String or int...

```
 @PostMapping("/showCompany")
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("company") CompaniesDAO company, String company_name, String company_function) {
```

It turns out VariableDeclaratorId is a class

```
public class VariableDeclaratorId
extends Expression
implements prettyprint.PrettyPrintable
```

If you read the class description using it with the error message to determine that you forgot to define the variable type, I am impressed; I simply made an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you forgot to add the main method,

```
public class Tutorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        static Random rnd = new Random();
        entity player;
        player.health = 100;  // Issue on the health part
        player.accuracy = 19; // Issue on the accuracy part
        player.power = 15;    // Issue on the power part
        player.defense = 18;  // I think you get it by now...
    }

}
```

and

```
class entity{
    public int health;
    public int accuracy;
    public int power;
    public int defense;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Two bugs I can notice in the above code

1. method signature of

   /*
   public static void main(String[] arg) {}
   */

is missing.

2. You're trying to access properties of an object without creating an object.
   Since player is pointing to null.
   What you're essentially trying to do is

   //null.health = 100